# service worker (Inactive) in Google Search - Geolocation & Language Change (Google Chrome extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service

Today I installed the Google Chrome extension Extension Manager which turned off all the extensions; then I uninstalled it, and the result is that the extension Geolocation & Language Change gives me this message "service worker (Inactive)":

[image]

I tried to uninstall and install it again, but the result is the same; the button "Location" doesn't do anything:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try restarting the browser after uninstalling the extension.

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm I tried, but it's still inactive.